# Python Array To Csv, Group data from a CSV file by field value and save csv

Tags: python, csv

i have a csv file

```
col1      col2
a          1     
a          2        
a          3    
b          3      
b          6    
b          1
```

i use this code

```
import csv

result = {}

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvreader:
        if row[0] in result:
            result[row[0]].append(row[1])
        else:
            result[row[0]] = [row[1]]

print result

output 
result:{
    'a': ['1', '2', '3'], 
    'b': ['3', '6', '1'] 
}
```

Now i want save this result to csv file(i want use this method)
result.csv

a    b
1    3
2    6
3    1

**SOLVED**

```
df_zor = pd.read_csv('5_gecici_.csv', encoding = "windows-1250", sep=';')
df = df_zor.groupby("gorevli").agg(lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).T
df.apply(lambda x: np.pad(x.iloc[0], (0, df.apply(lambda x: len(x.iloc[0]), axis=0).max() - len(x.iloc[0])), 'constant', constant_values=np.nan), axis=0)[df_zor.gorevli.unique()].to_excel('5_gorevli_bazinda_incelemede_dosya_listesi.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: What is preventing you from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
to_csv = []

#to get 'a' and 'b' in first row
to_csv.append(list(result.keys()))

# To get 'a' and 'b' values
for a,b in  zip(*list(result.values())):
    to_csv.append([a,b])

# Writing result.csv
with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(to_csv)
```

The data in `result.csv` is :

```
a,b
1,3
2,6
3,1
```

Comment: Thank You Monnish, ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) i have error, may be #for a,b in zip(*list(result.values())):, im using python 3.7 , i have  a lot of colmuns,  col1,col2,col3.......col20

Comment: @eroniko if there are many columns you can use `for i in zip(*list(result.values())): to_csv.append(list(i))` here i will be an array of values at same position in columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
results_df = pd.DataFrame(data=result)
results_df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this at the end:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as fw:
    cw = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',')
    row_list = list(result.keys()) + [x for x in zip(*result.values())]
    cw.writerows(row_list)
```

EDIT: I see my answer is a bit late. My answer is identical to @Mohnish answer except I use a "list comprehension" instead of explicitly looping through the zip object. @Mohnish answer has more explanation so go with that.

EDIT: Basically, instead of this:

```
# To get 'a' and 'b' values
for a,b in  zip(*list(result.values())):
    to_csv.append([a,b])
```

do this:

```
to_csv += [x for x in zip(*result.values())]
```

Comment: Thank You James, ------ ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) i have error, may be #for a,b in zip(*list(result.values())):, im using python 3.7 , i have a lot of colmuns, col1,col2,col3.......col20 –

Comment: Did you try my solution? Your comment has the word `for` in it, and my solution does not have the word `for` in it. As I said, I used a "list comprehension".